# How do I show my favicon when I share my website on discord?

Tags: html, discord

You know how in discord, when you share a link, sometimes the icon of the website shows up? How do I achieve a similar effect. For reference, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

See how there's an icon of google meet on the right side of the description? How do I achieve that effect? Should I add a new meta tag on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this and showing your logo or image in an embed when posting your website on Discord, you can use the HTML meta tag with `property`. For the image you would use it like `property="og:image"` and description `property="og:description"`. You can also set a title which is `og:title`.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AndBj.png?s=48&g=1"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="StackOverflow" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="StackOverflow" />
</head>
<body>
  hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Example of how it would look on Discord:

[image]
[image]